# bluebird promise catch() is not calling inner function with Promise.CancellationError

Tags: javascript, node.js, promise, bluebird

When a file is missing, I am trying to cancel the promise. However, when I do this I see in the output:

```
Unhandled rejection Error: ENOENT, open '/home/one/github/infrastructure_manager_ui/gulp/util/token-file.json'
  at Error (native)
```

and also `createTokenFile()` does not run as it should. Not sure what I am doing wrong:

```
 function refreshToken() {
        var tokenFile = path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
        return tokenPromise = fs.readFileAsync(tokenFile, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
        .then(JSON.parse)
        .cancellable()
        .catch(Promise.CancellationError, function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') { 
                throw err;
            } else {
                createTokenFile();
                tokenPromise.cancel();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: Why are you trying to cancel a promise from it's own handler?!

Answer (score 1):

`.cancellable()` is not doing anything here. `.cancellable()` turns a promise into one can be manually cancelled. You're not doing anything to cancel it here, so it's not being cancelled.

If you want to catch the file read error, you should just catch it:

```
function refreshToken() {
        var tokenFile = path.join(__dirname, 'token-file.json');
        return tokenPromise = fs.readFileAsync(tokenFile, {encoding: 'utf-8'})
        .then(JSON.parse)
        .catch(function(err) {
            console.log(err);
            if (err.code !== 'ENOENT') { 
                throw err;
            } else {
                return createTokenFile();
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: No, I need to cancel the promise also. I tried `tokenPromise.cancel();` from inside the else block but no luck

Comment: @dman You can't cancel a promise that has already completed, which it would be if you were already inside that else block. And execution will not even enter that `catch` handler in your code unless the promise was already cancelled. You seem to be misunderstanding what promise cancellation does. Please see [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28487148/promise-cancellation-still-firing-fulfill-function/28487478#28487478) for a clarification.