# Can we use multiple then in single promise returned function?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, promise, callback

Following is my code -

```
const fn = () => new Promise((resolve, reject) => reject());
let promise = fn();

promise
.then(() => console.log('Success 1'))
.then(() => console.log('Success 2'))
.then(() => console.log('Success 3'))
.catch(() => console.log('Error 1'))
.then(() => console.log('Success 4'))
.catch(() => console.log('Error 2'))
.then(() => console.log('Success 5'))
.catch(() => console.log('Error 3'))
```

Which is returning -

```
"Error 1"
"Success 4"
"Success 5"
```

My question is when a promise is settled in catch with a output `Error 1` then why `Success 4` and `Success 5` gets logged in the console ?

Comment: because catch also returns a promise

Comment: Anyone have a really good dupetarget for this? I'm sure there is one, but what I'm finding is different enough to be confusing.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder How about this one? [Executing then after catch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28446869/executing-then-after-catch)

Comment: @JeffBowman - Perfect!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of the key things about `then` and `catch` is that *they return a new promise*. That new promise is settled based on A) What happens to the promise you call `then` or `catch` on, and B) What happens inside the handler function you provide (what it returns, or the error it throws).

In your code, you're catching a rejection via `catch`, and then you're returning `undefined` from it (because `console.log` returns `undefined`, and you're returning its return value) — which fulfills the promise `catch` created (rather than rejecting it) with the value `undefined`, so the fulfillment handler you hooked up with `then` gets called. That handler also returns `undefined`, fulfilling its promise, so the next `then` handler gets called.

In a `catch` handler function, if you want to reject the promise `catch` created, either throw an error or return a promise that is/will be rejected.